# VBA: changing data through a range vs. array

Tags: arrays, vba, performance, loops

I am trying to make my macro run faster.  My spreadsheet is 300,000 rows and as part of the macro I am trying to change the values of columns AF & AG to values that depend on the value of column A.

I did this using a loop function, but I heard that using an array would be faster.  I switched to the array code below and the macro runs about 5 seconds longer.  Is there a more efficient way to code to save time on this step?

**Code 1**

```
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Range("A2:A400000")
   If cell.Value = "N149933" _
   Or cell.value = "N103291" _
   Or cell.value = "NS11375" _
   Or cell.value = "N187037" _
   Or cell.value = "N132921" _
   Or cell.value = "NS03359" _
   Or cell.value = "N102301" Then
      cell.Offset(0,32).Value = "Foundation and Endowment (Charities)"
      cell.Offset(0,31).Value = "QP"
ElseIf cell.Value = "NS35481" Then
      cell.Offset(0,32).Value = "Corporate"
ElseIf cell.Value = "NS07301" Then
      cell.Offset(0,32).Value = "Public Fund (Government)"
      cell.Offset(0,31).Value = "QP"
ElseIf cell.value = "NS29802" _
    Or cell.value = "NS29803" _
    Or cell.value = "NS29801" Then
      cell.Offset(0,32).Value = "Insurance"
  Else: cell.Offset(0,32).Value = "High Net Worth Individuals"
  End If
Next Cell
```

**Code 2**

```
Dim arr as Variant
arr = Worksheets("Input").Range("A1").CurrentRegion

Dim i as Long
For i = LBound(arr,1) + 1 To UBound(arr,1)
   If arr(i,1) = "N149933" _
   Or arr(i,1) = "N103291" _
   Or arr(i,1) = "NS11375" _
   Or arr(i,1) = "N187037" _
   Or arr(i,1) = "N132921" _
   Or arr(i,1) = "NS03359" _
   Or arr(i,1) = "N102301" Then
     arr(i,32) = "QP"
     arr(i,33) = "Foundation and Endowment (Charities)"
ElseIf arr(i,1) = "NS35481" Then
     arr(i,33) = "Corporate"
ElseIf arr(i,1) = "NS07301" Then
     arr(i,32) = "QP"
     arr(i,33) = "Public Fund (Government)"
ElseIf arr(i,1) = "NS29802" _
    Or arr(i,1) = "NS29803" _
    Or arr(i,1) = "NS29801" Then
     arr(i,33) = "Insurance"
Else: arr(i,33) = "High Net Worth Individuals"
EndIf
Next i

Worksheets("Input").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.ClearContents

Dim rowCount As Long, columnCount As Long
rowCount = UBound(arr,1)
columnCount = UBound(arr,2)
Worksheets("Input").Range("A1").Resize(rowCount,columnCount).Value = arr
```

Comment: How about using a dictionary instead of conditionals? ``arr(i,1)=dictionary(arr(i,1))``? Also I would first store the working range into a variable and omit clearing contents. Not sure about the speed impact but it should make the code easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it is slower due to clearcontents, which you don't need as you don't change the size of the array. Furthermore you should use Application.screenupdating = false etc, see here https://www.spreadsheet1.com/how-to-optimize-vba-performance.html

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not using ClearContents will speed things up.

Also, a Select Case might make the code more readable but probably won't have any affect on performance.

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim arr As Variant
Dim I As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    Set rng = Worksheets("Input").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    arr = rng.Value

    For I = LBound(arr, 1) + 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        Select Case arr(I, 1)
            Case "N149933", "N103291", "NS11375", "N187037", "N132921", "NS03359", "N102301"
                arr(I, 32) = "QP"
                arr(I, 33) = "Foundation and Endowment (Charities)"
            Case "NS35481"
                arr(I, 33) = "Corporate"
            Case "NS07301"
                arr(I, 32) = "QP"
                arr(I, 33) = "Public Fund (Government)"
            Case "NS29802", "NS29803", "NS29801"
                arr(I, 33) = "Insurance"
            Case Else
                arr(I, 33) = "High Net Worth Individuals"
        End Select
    Next I

    rng.Value = arr
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Comment: `Set rng = Worksheets("Input").Range("A1")` - Did you miss `CurrentRegion` as per OP's code?

Comment: Hi norie thanks for the reply.  I am getting Run-time error '6': Overflow on arr = rng.Value any idea why that would come up?

Comment: I tested with a simple mock up of 300,000 rows with random 'NS' values in column A and didn't get any error. What data do you have in the other columns?

Comment: The table is 57 columns wide by 299,958 rows.  Is that too much for an array?  The columns contain anything from text to numbers to blanks depending on the column.

Comment: Not sure if it matters but how about just pull 2 arrays (1 for `A` and 1 for `AF:AG`) you would only then need to write 2 columns of data?

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely go through an array, not individual cell updates. Then it may be good to disable calculations and screen updating.

It is redundant to clear the range contents, normally this should have minimal impacts but clearly your range is quite substantial. I would probably try to do the mapping using a dictionary, they are surprisingly fast.

And finally, put the working range into a variable, you refer to it in multiple places, so it makes the code easier to read and rework.

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Dim d as Object: set d = CreateObject(Scripting.Dictionary)
    With d
        .Add "N149933","Foundation and Endowment (Charities)"
        .Add "N103291","Foundation and Endowment (Charities)"
        .Add "NS11375","Foundation and Endowment (Charities)"
        .Add "N187037","Foundation and Endowment (Charities)"
        .Add "N132921","Foundation and Endowment (Charities)"
        .Add "NS03359","Foundation and Endowment (Charities)"
        .Add "N149933","Foundation and Endowment (Charities)"
        .Add "N102301","Foundation and Endowment (Charities)"
        .Add "NS07301","Public Fund (Government)"
        .Add "NS35481","Corporate"
        .Add "NS29802","Foundation and Endowment (Charities)"
        .Add "NS29803","Foundation and Endowment (Charities)"
        .Add "NS29801","Insurance"
    End With

Dim rn as range: set rn = Worksheets("Input").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
Dim arr as Variant
arr = rn

Dim i as Long
For i = LBound(arr,1) + 1 To UBound(arr,1) + 1 'IMO you forgot to apply to the last row
   arr(i,33) = d(arr(i,1))
       If len(arr(i,33)) = 0 Then arr(i,33) = "High Net Worth Individuals"

       If Not (arr(i,33) = "Corporate" Or _
       arr(i,33) = "Insurance" Or _
       arr(i,33) = "High Net Worth Individuals" Then
           arr(i,32) = "QP"
       End If

Next i

rn.value = arr

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```